# Prove that the density is the same under product measure

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $P_0$ and $P_1$ be two probability measures on a measure space $X$ which are absolutely continuous with respect to some dominating measure $\mu$. Let $Q$ be a probability measure on measure space $Y$.

If suppose $\frac{dP_0}{d\mu}=p_0$ and $\frac{dP_1}{d\mu}=p_1$, I want to prove that $\frac{\frac{d (P_0 \times Q)}{d(\mu \times Q)}\left(x,y\right)}{\frac{d (P_1 \times Q)}{d(\mu \times Q)}\left(x,y\right)}=\frac{p_0(x)}{p_1(x)}$.

Can anyone give me a useful hint to prove this?

First I tried to prove that $\frac{d (P_0 \times Q)}{(d\mu \times Q)}\left(x,y\right)=p_0(x) q(y)$ where $q$ is the density of $Q$ w.r.t some dominating measure. Is this true?

Answer (score 0):

The solution to your problem is simple. In fact all you need to observe is that if $P << \mu,$ and $\frac{dP}{d\mu}= p(x),$ you find: $$\frac{d(P \otimes Q)}{d(\mu \otimes Q)} = p(x)$$

This is because on any product set $A = A_1 \times A_2,$ $$P \otimes Q(A) = P(A_1) \cdot Q(A_2) = \int \int 1_{A_1}(x)p(x) d\mu(dx) 1_{A_2}(y) dQ(dy) = \int p(x) 1_{A_1 \times A_2}(x,y)d(\mu \otimes Q)(dx, dy)$$

You can extend this statement to the whole sigma-field by a monotone-class argument.